# How to iterate through the object in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have data like below,

```
[{
  "Ebstein's anomaly": {
    "overview Question": {
      "0": {
        "field1": "What is Ebstein's anomaly?",
        "field2": "<strong>Ebstein's anomaly</strong> is a rare heart defect in which parts of the tricuspid valve.<br />",
        "dateModified": "April 30th 2014, 5:45:00 pm"
      }
    },
    "phenotypes": {
      "0": {
        "field1": "Abnormality of the tricuspid valve"
      },
      "1": {
        "field1": "Atria septal defect"
      },
      "2": {
        "field1": "Premature birth"
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

Here I want to append the data like the format below using node js into a file.

```
Ebstein's anomaly
  overview Question:
     What is Ebstein's anomaly
     Ebstein's anomaly</strong> is a rare heart defect in which parts of the tricuspid valve.<br />
     DATE MODIFIED:April 30th 2014, 5:45:00 pm
```

I tried this

```
newItems.forEach(function(v,i){
  for (var key in v) {
    if (v.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var dataT = v;
      for (var key in dataT) {
        if (dataT.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log(v)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am new to nodejs and I have no idea on data preparation, Can anyone please give me a clue.Thanks.

Comment: How to decide whether to output the key, the value or both?